# $NP^{PP} vs. PP^{NP}$, which one subsumes the other?

Tags: computational-complexity, automata, turing-machines

I understand why P with an NP oracle ($P^{NP}$) subsumes $NP$: because it contains co-NP. But how about NP with a P oracle? Can it be any different from NP? (I'm guessing they are the same otherwise $NP^P$ would've appeared in the polynomial hierarchy)

Going further, How does it all stand with class PP (probabilistic polynomial time) assuming the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse?

- $PP^{NP} = PP$?
- $P^{PP} = PP$?
- $NP^{PP} vs. PP^{NP}$, which one subsumes the other?

Any reasoning (intuition) as to why this does (not) hold?

Answer (score 2):

Since $P \subseteq NP$, $NP^P = NP$.

Nondeterministic programs are an extension of deterministic programs. They are just programs with a jump-and-branch command added.  So every deterministic program is also a nondeterminnistic program that doesn't use jump-and-branch, so adding the oracle gives no additional computability.

Comment: I don't like that first sentence at all; after all, $NP\subseteq NP$, but $NP^{NP}\neq NP$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Hmm, that's true I didn't think too hard about it.  Thanks for the correction.  In fact, if $P=NP$ then $NP^P$ collapses to whatever time it takes to call the oracle ($O(n)$ to write the input or whatever).  I guess the question was harder than it appeared at first glance.